# Bash alias cpu usage

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I've tried this command but I have a percentage error calculator:

```
alias cpu="mpstat | awk '\$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print 100 - $12\"%\" }'"
```

Thank you for help

Comment: What output do you get? What did you expect?

Comment: You forgot to escape the `$` in the `print` command; `$1` is being expanded when the alias is defined.

Comment: correct output is 1.6% but i get 98%

Comment: Your quoting problems go away if you use a function instead: `cpu() { mpstat ... `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
alias cpu="mpstat | awk '\$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print 100 - \$12\"%\" }'"
```

`\` was missing after `100 -`.

```
-> mpstat
Linux 3.2.0-69-virtual (myhost)     01/06/2017  _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

10:18:16 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
10:18:16 PM  all   12.06    7.00    7.96    0.02    0.00    0.24    0.22    0.00   72.49

-> cpu
27.51%
```